# Probability of a gaussian distrbution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Assume that we have two variables $V_0$ and $\Delta V$, we know that $V_o$ follows a gaussian probability distribution. So what would be the $P(V_o< \Delta V)$ knowing $\sigma_o$ (The standard deviation of $V_o$). Also the mean of the PDF is zero.

Comment: Specify what $\sigma_0$ is. The mean of who is zero ?

Comment: well $\sigma_o$ is the standard deviation of the $V_o$ and the mean of the PDF is zero.

Comment: What do you know about $\Delta V$?

Comment: $\Delta V$ is something that you yourself determine, it is a variable. Basically the probability should be a function of $\sigma_0$ and $\Delta V$. So basically $\Phi (\Delta V, \sigma_o)$

Answer (score 1):

If $\Delta V$ is not random, than 
$$P(V_0 < \Delta V) = \Phi_{\sigma_0}(\Delta V)$$
is just a distribution function of zero mean Gaussian distribution with variance $\sigma_0^2$ and you can find it on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).

Comment: shouldn't it be $\Phi (\Delta V / \sigma_o)$ since you are using the standard normal distribution.

Comment: Yes, there is a mistake, I skipped the end of sentence. I'll edit the answer.